# Lock bootloader with broken USB port

Tags: usb, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I bought a Xiaomi Mi A2 maybe 10 months from now, and from changing software, or some strange things, I broke the USB port.

The strange thing is that only the "OTG" part got broken. I mean, I still can charge the phone, and use the native USB-C to Micro-Jack convertor, but I cannot use USB-C headphones or correct the phone to my PC.

I sent the phone to the warranty service, but since I had unlocked the bootloader, they didn't cover the charges. It was in christmas, so they didn't even wanted to fix anything, the just sent me the phone back.

But as a developer, I really need USB Debugging, and I bought some nice USB-C headphones, and I can't use them, so I wonder if there's anything I can do to relock the bootloader, and maybe send the phone to them for a repair.

Any ideas? I'd be really pleased. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Only thing i can think of is maybe it was dropped while being charged and the usb jack is slightly bent inside...

ALWAYS TRY ANOTHER  CONFIRMED WORKING USB CABLE FIRST !

- Start Fastboot on the PC
- Use `wait-for-device` or just `devices` first
- `fastboot wait-for-device` or `fastboot devices`
- You should see "waiting for device"

A worthy mention..
This will require your fastboot commands to be constructed as a script file.  .

- write each command in a new text file, line by line
  ( one command per line )
- Save the text document as a .bat file on Windows or a .sh file on linux
- Run the script

  - if .bat ( Double Click )
  - if .sh ( use command sh -c /path/script.sh )

  SCRIPT CONTENTS EXAMPLE

  ```
  fastboot wait-for-device
  fastboot oem lock
  ```

Script will vary slightly with linux ( !#sbin/sh)

Fastboot should wait for a connection and then execute the next command ( oem lock )

To Use All Of This ...

- Start the script on PC
- Plug in the USB to PC but not Device ( important )
- Now the tricky part, Slowly plug in the USB cable to the device, try to apply a slight amount of pressure going in a circle to find the sweet spot ( the part where the terminals are touching - the angle that the usb is bent on.. )

Try to find the spot where there's a connection, and watch the script run...
You are trying to hold the USB connection for just long enough to run OEM Lock, Fastboot will wait for the sweet spot ( only just connecting ) and then run OEM Lock after it gets a connection...

Comment: P.S you might have turned USB Charge Only - On